# jQuery, animate and animate back. Call back function error? :S

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, animation, callback

I have no idea what I've done. The idea is to animate an element to slide in from a position and slide back when another element has been click. I've applied the second event within the call back of the original event function.

But, despite this structure, the second event function will run although I've not clicked the second element in the callback function.

If you're not following, the basic idea is this.

Click -> slidein -> outside click -> slide out

```
$('#mobileList').click(function(){
    $('#mobileMenu').css({'display':'block'}).animate({
        'left':'30%'
    },500,function(){
        $('#body').click(function(){
            $('#mobileMenu').animate({
                'left':'100%'
            },500,function(){$('#mobileMenu').css({'display':"none"});/* I tried return false; here, failed to solve problem*/});
        });
    });         
});
```

Starting CSS

```
nav#mobileMenu{display:none;width:70%;height:100%;background:#191820;color:#DCDCDC;position:fixed;top:0;left:100%;}
```

How the elements are structured.

```
<div id="body">
    <a id="mobileList>&#9776;</a>
    <!-- content here -->
</div>
<nav id="mobileMenu">
    <!-- content -->
</nav>
```

On the first two attempts it works fine. The next time I come to run, it will animate and then immediately animated out. I really can't see why as it's a call back function? :S

I think it's because the element `#mobileList` is within the element `#body`.

Is the call back still running? Can I cease it looking for the event?

Should I use `queue()` to run the slide in and slide out?

Comment: You are nesting click handlers, bad idea!

Comment: I thought so :p is there another method you could recommend?

Comment: Doesn't Rory's answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the callback here, just hook the `click` handlers up separately:

```
$('#mobileList').click(function(){
    $('#mobileMenu').show().stop(true).animate({
        'left': '30%'
    }, 500);         
});

$('#body').click(function(){
    $('#mobileMenu').stop(true).animate({
        'left': '100%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j0r95kth/)

Note that I used `show`/`hide` instead of `css` and added calls to `stop()` to prevent the queue being filled up on successive clicks during animation.

---

*UPDATE*

To hide the menu when you click anywhere else you need to attach an event handler to the `document` and check `e.target` to see what element caused the event. If it was outside the menu, hide it.

```
$('#mobileList').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#mobileMenu').show().stop(true).animate({ 'left': '30%' }, 500);
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    var $menu = $('#mobileMenu');
    if (!$menu.is(e.target) && !$menu.has(e.target).length) {
        $('#mobileMenu').stop(true).animate({ 'left': '100%' }, 500, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j0r95kth/2/)

Comment: ohh yea :d Sorry, I feel stupid now XD been a long time since I've done DOM stuff!! Thanks :) hang on, I've just realised my problem. Two secs I'll change my question.

Comment: Found my problem. `$('mobileList')` is within `#body` so both are started simultaneously :p

Comment: Is there a selector I could use that selects everything but the element `#mobileMenu`? :d

Comment: Are you trying to hide the `mobileMenu` when anything else gets clicked?

Comment: yes :) I would do `$('body').not('#mobileMenu').click()` but not sure this will work?

Comment: Cool thank you :) Never seen something like that before :) Thanks a lot! I shall see how it all works by taking it apart! Wohahahaha :d